# Why does iterating over entry set not work?

Tags: java, hashmap, entryset

I try to iterate over an EntrySet like this:

```
 for (Entry<A, List<B>> list : service.entrySet()) {
                if (list.getKey() == typ1) {
                    for (B current : list.getValue()) {                            
                      // do sth
                    }
                }
               
                } else {
                    PrintHelper.printOut("not implemented case"
                            + list.getKey());
                }
            }
       }
```

Even though I have that part `if (list.getKey() == typ1)`  I still get the printed case `not implemented case typ1`.

Why is that the case? What am I doing wrong with the iteration/ the if case?

Comment: Are `typ1` and the return value of `list.getKey()` strings, or any kind of object? If so, compare them with `equals()`, not with ' ==' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key of a Map (or map entry) is an object - you need to compare it with `equals`, not `==`:

```
if (list.getKey().equals(typ1)) {
```